# Forget Email not send the email to customer in magento 1 but in code the mailer function sent the email

Tags: php, email, magento-1.9, mailer, custom-errors

I am facing a issues with forget password issues the in magneto 1.9 .i am using the default forget password Transactional email template . i have also debug the code there in core file the mailer function send the email but i did not get it in email account.
In addition, i have created a custom template forget password.and setup it from the system-> comfiguration-> customer settings . than it will worked. it will send the email . but am concerns with default forgetpassword email template why it will not send the email to custom email.

I have  debug the code at core file:- 
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
 public function forgotPasswordPostAction()
    {
     $email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
     if ($email) {

        //echo "email".$email;
        if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
            $this->_getSession()->setForgottenEmail($email);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Invalid email address.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
            return;
        }

        /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = $this->_getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
            ->loadByEmail($email);

               if ($customer->getId()) {
  //echo "email".$customer->getID();die;
               try {
                $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  $this->_getHelper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
         $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
                $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
               } catch (Exception $exception) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($exception->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_getSession()
            ->addSuccess( $this->_getHelper('customer')
            ->__('If there is an account associated with %s you will receive an email with a link to reset your password.',
                $this->_getHelper('customer')->escapeHtml($email)));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please enter your email.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
        return;
    }
}
```

/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
    protected function _sendEmailTemplate($template, $sender, $templateParams = array(), $storeId = null)
{
    /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

   $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
   $emailInfo->addTo($this->getEmail(), $this->getName());
   $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);


    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig($sender, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId(Mage::getStoreConfig($template, $storeId));
    $mailer->setTemplateParams($templateParams);
    $mailer->send();
   // debug code 
     if($mailer->send()){
        echo "mailer sent";
    }else{
        echo "not sent";
     }
            return $this;
}
```

Can any one help me to resolved it.